# How to use functions as arguments in python

Tags: python, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I need to pass a function as a parameter shown in the code below:

```
import math
global alpha

alpha = 15
```

This is one evaluation of a problem:

```
def vaike(sisend):
    return ((1+0.001*alpha)**sisend)/(10+alpha)
```

This is another:

```
def suur(sisend):
    return (math.log(10+alpha)*x)/math.log(1+0.001*alpha)
```

And now this function must operate with the exact order of parameters as shown here
such that x0 is something given by the user and g() is chosen from the functions
above, eps and maxit are limiters:

```
def iterator(x0,g(),eps,maxit):
    a=x0
    b=g(a)
    for i in range(maxit):
        if abs(b-a)<eps or (i+1)==maxit:
            return b
        else:
            a=b
            b=g(a)

print(iterator(10,vaike(10),0.000001,200))
```

How can I call the last function as shown on the previous line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your function should look like:

```
def iterator(x0,g,eps,maxit):  ## Changed g() to g
    a=x0
    b=g(a)
    for i in range(maxit):
        if abs(b-a)<eps or (i+1)==maxit:
            return b
        else:
            a=b
            b=g(a)

print(iterator(10,vaike,0.000001,200)) ## Changed vaike(10) to vaike
```

This will work.